# Formatting Unix Timestampe to Python Datetime - Using Windows

Tags: python, datetime, unix, timestamp

I've read many posts; however, I am unable resolve this problem.

I am using Windows, so I understand that Unix timestamp is displayed in milliseconds; therefore I divided the integer by 1,000. However, I still received `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Unix timestamp to datetime conversion function:

```
def unix_to_datetime(x):    
    if type(x) == int:
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    else:
        date = x
    return date
```

I reference this function by `df_rank['date_formatted'] = df_rank['date'].apply(lambda x: unix_to_datetime(x))`

**df_rank** dataframe below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the changes as below.

```
def unix_to_datetime(x):   
    try:
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    except:
        date = x
    return date
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The Unix code is multiplied by 1 billion, not 1 thousand. I guess it's cause I combined a total of 5 columns using `fillna()`.

Correct code:

```
def unix_to_datetime(x):    
    try:
        y = x / 1000000000
        date_str = datetime.fromtimestamp(y).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    except:
        date = x
    return date
```

Comment: to clarify: `datetime.fromtimestamp` expects the input to be *seconds* since the epoch. `pandas` datetime is internally stored as *nanoseconds* since the epoch - which seems to be what you have... this is why you have to divide by 1e9.